# How to create tenant in keycloak without master realm?

Tags: python, flask, keycloak

I am trying to understand a usecase where a web application can authenticate with keycloak server with the following scenarios

1. Create a realm dynamically from a sign up page(trying to achieve multi tenancy)
2. Realm has its own authentication properties from user creations to roles assignment.
3. Authenticate a user against a realm from the provided subdomain.
   Instead of mapping user with tenant name and doing a get call on the 
   service to get the tenant name.
   Because the documentation states that tenant name is needed for user authentication.

From the UI I understand that:
1. we need to get token from master realm 
   http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
2. Then create a realm 
   http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test

Im not sure if this is a secure workflow.
And not sure if I have to create a client after creating a realm.

Appreciate some thoughts on this.

Comment: Hi! Did you found a clue?

Comment: Hi, We tried maintaining a database table with all the tenants and their metadata. And every new request we fetch the data from the db and customize the flow.

Comment: That's a cool idea.